# build groups with LAG, FIRST_VALUE etc

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping, aggregate-functions

an ordered query delivers this result:

```
val1    val2    val3                        id  
1303    1303    22.03.18 14:00:03.915000000 1
1303    1303    22.03.18 14:00:07.800000000 2
1303    1303    23.03.18 12:15:03.798000000 3
1303    1303    23.03.18 12:15:09.345000000 4
9999    1303    23.03.18 21:00:00.000000000 5
1303    1303    23.03.18 23:15:09.345000000 6
9999    1303    23.03.18 23:18:09.345000000 7
9999    1303    23.03.18 23:19:09.345000000 8
1303    1303    23.03.18 23:20:09.345000000 9
1303    1303    23.03.18 23:55:09.345000000 10
```

the Thing i try to do now is to build groups. whenever val1 is changing a new group should be created with the rowid of first row of this group. whenever val1 is 9999, it always has to be an own single group that keeps its rowid. the result i Need is:

```
val1    val2    val3                        id  
1303    1303    22.03.18 14:00:03.915000000 1
1303    1303    22.03.18 14:00:07.800000000 1
1303    1303    23.03.18 12:15:03.798000000 1
1303    1303    23.03.18 12:15:09.345000000 1
9999    1303    23.03.18 21:00:00.000000000 5
1303    1303    23.03.18 23:15:09.345000000 6
9999    1303    23.03.18 23:18:09.345000000 7
9999    1303    23.03.18 23:19:09.345000000 8
1303    1303    23.03.18 23:20:09.345000000 9
1303    1303    23.03.18 23:55:09.345000000 9
```

i thought that should be possible by using functions like LAG, FIRST_VALUE etc. wahtever i try, i don get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've arrived at this code, which might well have room for improvement:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT val1, id, lag(val1) over(ORDER BY id) lg 
  FROM test
)
, t2 AS (
  SELECT val1, id, lg
  , last_value(decode(val1,9999,id,lg,NULL,id) ignore nulls) over(ORDER BY id) lv 
  FROM t1
)
SELECT  t2.id, t2.val1, rank() over(ORDER BY lv) r
FROM t2
ORDER BY id
```

---

```
ID  VAL1  R 
--- ----- --
1   1303  1 
2   1303  1 
3   1303  1 
4   1303  1 
5   9999  5 
6   1303  6 
7   9999  7 
8   9999  8 
9   1303  9 
10  1303  9
```

Comment: well done! exactly what i Need, i was pretty close to that, many thanks...